# How to create a 2D "perspective"/trapezoid view in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, 2d

Drawing a 2D view in OpenGL is simple: just use `GLOrtho`.  But as far as I can tell, that will always give you a rectangular view.  But what if you want a slightly more sophisticated perspective?

Assume that I've got a map that's significantly larger than my viewport, and I want to draw it to a perspective trapezoid view where the bottom (near) side is narrower than the far side.  But I still want everything to be 2D.

How do I set up the viewport to display that way, ideally without having to change my actual drawing code any?  I'd like to be able to just set a new viewport and then draw everything to the same coordinates and have OpenGL work out the perspective view.

A basic illustration of the type of effect I'm looking for:  Final Fantasy 4's airship view

[image: FF4 airship view]

Anyone know how to set that up?  Let's say, just for the sake of throwing some numbers out there, that my basic viewport is 800x600, and I'd like the trapezoid view to display the same 800 pixels along the bottom but 1200 along the top.

Comment: For historical context, [you too can achieve Mode 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_7).

Comment: @K.G.: Yeah, I've seen that article.  It says that a "pseudo-perspective" required creatively hacking around with matrices on a scanline-per-scanline basis, (a concept that doesn't exist in OpenGL) and it doesn't say anything about what sort of matrix math was needed.

Comment: Sure they do!  Look under the "Formula" heading.  "Planar texture maps using Mode 7 graphics are generated by transforming screen coordinates to background coordinates using a 2D affine transformation..."

Comment: @K.G.: I saw that.  Look at the next paragraph, where it explains the limits of that technique and explicitly states that other things, including perspective view, required unspecified per-scanline manipulation tricks.

Comment: Gotcha.  It doesn't answer your question, I just thought it was an interesting curiosity.  Incidentally, have you taken a look at [Nicol Bolas' OpenGL tutorial series](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html)?

Comment: @K.G.: Yeah, I've seen that.  It's an excellent tutorial, but it's all about 3D, and I'm trying to do 2D.

Comment: It's a more complicated topic than can be expressed in comments, but the long and the short of it is, there's no such thing as 2D, or more appropriately, there's no such thing as 3D.  I'm not saying that to be glib, but to accomplish what you want in OpenGL, you're going to end up using 3D transforms on a 2D object.  There's no way to get perspective without a transformation matrix.  If you want two separate planes (perspective for the overworld, orthographic/billboarded for sprites), the math has to get done somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use a perspective projection and tilt the view.

Comment: -1.  I'm sorry, but this is in no way an answer to my question.  I didn't ask "what" to do, I asked "how."  Projections and matrix math are not my strong suit.  Poking around on opengl.org's documentation, I have a vague idea that calling glOrtho, immediately followed by gluPerspective might be what I need to do, but the explanations are all in dense mathematical jargon with nothing actually useful such as sample code.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: You use gluPerspective instead of ortho, because, what you actually want to do, is looking at a plane with perspective. That I didn't give you more information is, because you didn't give us the required detail (how do you draw your scene, what kind of geometry do you use, etc.)

Comment: I draw the scene by rendering everything onto a render target and then rendering that to the screen as a single quad. That makes effects that affect the whole screen a lot easier.  So the question is basically equivalent to, "how do I render a single quad that's larger than the viewport and make it come out in a 2D trapezoid/perspective view like in the example screenshot?"  It's safe to assume that the quad is bigger *enough* that the view won't encompass the whole thing.  And I can use a point sprite to get the "sky above the horizon" effect; I'm only concerned about the map.

Comment: If you are using 3D openGL then render the 2D map onto a flat rectangular quad.  Set the transform of the quad itself to rotate it 45 degrees X (pitch).  There will be methods to change the transform in terms of rotation without needing to alter the matrix directly.  If it tilts the wrong way use 315 degrees X (pitch) instead.